# Oracle 18c XE Windows 10 - SQLPlus returns TNS-12560 but everything else works

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus, oracle18c, ora-12560

First, I understand there are lots of similar posts but I have googled a lot and haven't found the answer to this particular issue.

Second, I'm very new to Oracle (I'm a SQL Server guy) so please be patient.

Ok, so a few months I had a client who gave me an Oracle database backup to import into Oracle 18c XE on Windows 10 to then extract data out of it for them via a .Net program using ODP.Net 11.2.  I installed 18c XE and ODP.Net, created a user/schema and imported the backup using DBCA all using tutorials etc.  I could  connect to the user/schema in SQL Developer and do queries.  I ran my .Net program and all was well.

At that point I could connect to SQL plus using 'sys as sysdba' to execute commands like creating the user, granting privileges etc.  But now when I log in a few months later to do the same exercise on a new backup I can no longer connect to SQLPlus, always getting "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error" for any user. Everything else still works but I need SQLPlus to drop the user/schema so I can import the new backup.  The client's IT company say they haven't touched Oracle as this is set up just in my user account which no else would have logged in to except me.

So here are the checks I done so far from googling and reading posts on SO. (I've changed the master user and passwords to mike below but these have been tried with the real user and password)

- Checked services: OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener and OracleServiceXE are both running.
- Ran "lsnrctl status" and got the following which I assume looks OK (no errors anyway):

[image]

My listener and tnsnames.ora files look like this:

[image]

[image]

- ORACLE_SID = XE
- ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\mike\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE
- Tried SQLPLus using "sqlplus mike/mike@XE" and it logged me in though it gave me an error "SP2-0310: unable to open file "LOGIN.SQL"
- Tried SQLPLus using "sqlplus sys as sysdba/mike@XE" and yet again got the TNS-12560 error.

Finally I Looked in the listener log file in C:\app\mike\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\APP01\listener\alert and got the following which I also assume looks correct:

```html
<msg time='2020-05-29T12:38:48.315+10:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='APP01'
 host_addr='fe80::1dfb:94cd:7fac:9551%5' pid='25368'>
 <txt>29-MAY-2020 12:38:48 * service_update * xe * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

But still I can't connect to SQLPLus using sys - can anyone suggest what might be the issue and how I can fix it?  I just need to be able to log in to drop the user I created so I can import the new backup so this is incredibly frustrating!

TIA for any help rendered.

**** EDIT ****

SQLNet.ORA file:
[image]

ORACLE_SID / ORACLE_HOME (even though I listed these above)
[image]

Comment: Please post the content of the sqlnet.ora file.

Comment: Look for alert log  in `...\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\alert_XE.log`.Please use elevated command prompt and verify environment with `echo %ORACLE_SID%` and `echo %ORACLE_HOME%` and login in as sysdba `sqlplus / as sysdba`.You were  able to login as mike you can ignore that error`unable to open file login.sql`

Comment: For ""SP2-0310: unable to open file "LOGIN.SQL", check SQLPATH environment variable including Windows registry but yes you can ignore this error.

Comment: For TNS-12560 that you have only for SYSDBA connection: as already said, please post `sqlnet.ora` and check also if Windows account that runs sqlplus.exe is member of Windows group `ora_dba`.

Comment: If you try to login just with `sqlplus / as sysdba` does this work ? If not, try the same but before unset ORACLE_HOME with `set ORACLE_HOME=` .  does this work ?

Comment: Please see edits in my question for sqlnet,ora file and confirmation of ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME.   If I view the user I am logged in as in Local Users and Groups it can;t even find a group called "ora_dba" - do I need to look for this some other way?

Comment: sqlnet.ora, ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME are OK. Can you check output of `net user <your_Windows_account>`

Comment: @pifor, if I do "net user domain\user" it just gives the usage of the command.  If I only do "net user <myuser>" it says user does not exist.  (Obviously I can't show real logins or domains here)

Comment: BTW, ignore above comment about not being in ORA_DBA - I can see my account is a member.

Comment: So connecting with SYSDBA without using network connection should work. Can you try to login just with `sqlplus / as sysdba` And try the same but before unset ORACLE_HOME with `set ORACLE_HOME= ` .

Comment: No luck even after resetting ORACLE_HOME . It just gives me the same 12560 error.  I wonder if it could be because I installed two versions of ODP.Net 11.2 (32 bit and then 64 bit)?  I have checked all other network/admin folders for occurrences of the listener and tnsnames and renamed them so only the ones in ORACLE__HOME  should be used but maybe the two installs screwed something else up.  Just strange I could log in using sysdba when I first set it all up a few months back.

Comment: Just login as mike and what do you see sqlplus version 12.x or 18.x? or go to bin directory in in oracle home and login from there as `sqlplus / as sysdba` I had same problem after installing ODAC 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: I cannot explain why he does not work. But I suggest you first try *not* to use SYSDBA network connection as this requires small setup (no need to check Oracle Net stuff - in addition to Oracle Net you need to have a password file): local SYSDBA is easier to check.

Comment: If you have several ORACLE_HOME resetting ORACLE_HOME to an empty value could fix the local SYSDBA connection.

Comment: @sam, I ran SQLplus directly from the bin folder folder in 18c/home (ORACLE_HOME) using / as sysdba and it connected!   So what do you think is happening when I try sqlplus from anywhere else?  Would it be running a version from one of the ODP.net clients I ran?

Comment: Check your PATH setting and `where sqlplus.exe`; installing ODP has likely put another sqlplus.exe in the path.

Comment: You have two options  one create a batch file add `ORACLE_HOME`,`ORACLE_SID` and `path=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin` or go to system properties and remove odp.net client from path

Comment: Guys, thank you both SO MUCH for helping me out - I have been trying to solve this for days!   I will probably try cleaning up the path first then if that doesn't work I'll do the batch script or else just run sqlplus direct from the bin file in the future.

Comment: If you need odp.net clients go with batch file